# Should a 2FA app require authentication to grant access to 2FA tokens?

Tags: multi-factor

I don't know the theoretical background for 2FA so I'm asking here.

I've used a few 2FA apps before including Duo Mobile and Steam Mobile (Guard).
When Duo is opened, it will display your tokens as you expect, but with Steam your Guard token is displayed wether you are logged in or not. The Guard behavior caught my attention because I was expecting to need to be logged in first to see the token, since the token is tied to my account unlike with Duo where services are registered for use. That being said, Duo could use a master password (a la LastPass) so further protect the tokens.

So my question is do the workings behind 2FA (mobile apps specifically) consider if a user should be authenticated on the 2FA app to get access to tokens?

My theory is the security level is the same as SMS 2FA, where you can assume only the real user can access tokens because they know the phone's lock screen pin. In this system, the phone is the authenticator and exclusive access is granted by knowing the lock screen pin. But with 2FA apps, the app is the authenticator, but has no way to provide exclusive access. Anyone with access to the app (imagine a shared phone where 2+ people know the lock screen pin) can access the tokens.

Comment: How do you get access to the *authentication* token, then, before you are authenticated? That's like locking up your house key in the entryway. You need to unlock your house before unlocking your house. I'm also not sure about your difference between SMS and an app. Both require phone unlock access (or not, depending on the user's set up).

Comment: The fact that you share your *authentication* device with other people is a completely separate issue and not something that authentication designers are responsible to design for.

Answer (score 1):

The question here is about what you are protecting. The 2FA token protects the account's *password*. The idea is that the password is protected by the token. You can't log in with just the token, you need the password as the primary authentication method.

The reason why 2FA tokens are not made public (as opposed to being 'protected') is that if exposed arbitrarily, then they weaken the level of protection they offer. Tokens are protected to some level but only as far as the threats to the *password*.

If 2FA was to be a primary authentication factor, then there would be slightly different protections designed for it.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not necessary. The first factor (something they know) is the password for the account they're trying to log in to, and the second factor (something they have) is the phone that has the 2FA app on it. Putting a password on that is something else they know, so it's just another first factor, not an additional factor.